# " Use of uninitialised value" error with an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, hashtable, valgrind

I need to build a hash table but I get from Valgrind the error "Use of uninitialised value of size 8" on an array that is supposed to be initialized in the code (as you can see in HashTable's constructor).

Here's the class Magician :

```
 class Magician{
  public:
  int magiID;
  Magician(int id) : magiID(id) {}
 };
```

And here is the class HashTable:

```
 class HashTable {
 public:
   int k;//total size of the array
   int mod;
   Magician **array;

   HashTable(int k): k(k) {
     array = new Magician *[k];
     for(int i = 0; i<k; k++) array[i] = NULL; //Initialization of the array
     int mod(k);
     while ((mod%10 == 0)||(mod%2 == 0)) {
       mod--;
     }
     if(mod <= 1) mod = 2;
   }

 ~HashTable(){
   delete[] array;
 }

 int reHash(int x, int i){
   return (x%mod + i);
 }

 void insertElement(Magician* m){
   int id = m->magiID;
   int j = 0;
   while(array[reHash(id, j)%k] != NULL){ //Use of uninitialised value of size 8
      j++;
   }
   array[reHash(id, j)%k] = m; //Use of uninitialised value of size 8
 }

};
```

The problematic lines (that are in the method insertElement) are the ones who are trying to reach something in the array. Is my initialization bad ? If yes, then why ?

Comment: what is `used(0)` used for it is not a member variable ..??
Are you missing something in class definition ?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i<k; k++)`  : `k++` -> `i++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible culprit would be negative values in `magiID`. Note that the C and C++ `%` operator is defined so that `(a / b * b) + (a % b) == a`. If `a` is negative and `b` is positive, then the result is negative and you may index to before the beginning of the array.

Comment: Thank you very much, I haven't seen it.. It didn't affect the results but made the code very slow